# Get error: "Deserialization of interface types is not supported" while sending request (with field and file) to .NET 6 Web API

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am practicing passing value to a form in Angular, and then sending it with a file to .NET 6 Web API.

Here is what I do:

My HTML component:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" formControlName="name"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" formControlName="price"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td><input type="text" formControlName="quantity"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea formControlName="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" formControlName="status"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Photo</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" Name="photo" (change)="fileControl($event)">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>
                <select formControlName="categoryId">
                    <option value="1"> cate 1 </option>
                    <option value="2"> cate 2 </option>
                    <option value="3"> cate 3 </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here is my ts component:

```js
export class CreateApiComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    file: any;

    constructor(
        private productApiService: ProductApiService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private datePipe : DatePipe
    ){}

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: '',
            price: 0,
            quantity: 0,
            status: true,
            description: '',
            photo: '',
            categoryId: 1
        })

    }

    fileControl(e:any) {
        this.file = e.target.files[0];
    }

    submit() {      
        let product: ProductApi = this.form.value;
        product.created = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('data', this.file);

        this.productApiService.createWithFile(product, formData).then(
            res => {
                this.result = do something ;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);                
            }
        )
    }

}
```

And this is my `createWithFile` function, `baseUrl` is just a string containing "localhost:port/path":

```js
async createWithFile(product: Product, file: FormData) {
    return await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl+'create-with-file', {Product: product, Data: file}));
}
```

And this is my `productApi` class:

```js
export class ProductApi {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    status: boolean;
    description: string;
    created: string;
    photo: string;
    categoryId: number;
    categoryName: string;
}
```

Now to my ASP.NET, I'm using Entity Framework:
This is my `Product` class, the `Created` property got a `JsonConverter` to take care of it so no worry:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public double? Price { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public string? Photo { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I also create a model to catch the param from post request:

```cs
public class CreatedUpload
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Data { get; set; }        
}
```

This is my controller:

```cs
[HttpPost("create-with-file")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult CreateWithFile([FromBody] CreatedUpload createdUpload)
{
    try
    {
        *at this spot i put a debug to check the data in createdUpload*
        return Ok();
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Here is what I expect, I expect the `createdUpload` to catch `{Product: product, Data: file}` from the POST request, but instead I got this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'. Path: $.Data | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 144.

I also change the param of my `CreateWithFile` like this, but all of them return `null` (but not raise error):

```cs
[FromBody] Product product, [FromBody] IFormFile data
[FromForm] Product product, [FromForm] IFormFile data
```

I have read many questions in StackOverflow, but no answer can solve my problem, and I reach a dead end, please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the request body with `product` object and `file` as `FormData` to API.

1. Iterate the key properties of `product` object and add the key-value pair into `formData`. Note that it is required to have the prefix "product" in order to send the `product` object.

```js
submit() {      
  let product: ProductApi = this.form.value;
  product.created = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', this.file);

  // Add key-value pair into formData
  let key: keyof typeof product;
  for (k in product) {
    formData.append(`product.${k}`, product[k]);
  }

  this.productApiService.createWithFile(formData).then(
    res => {
      // Success
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);                
    }
  )
}
```

2. Modify the `createWithFile` method signature with `formData` parameter. Post the `formData`. Angular HttpClient will post the request with content-type: `multipart/form-data`.

```js
async createWithFile(formData: FormData){
    return await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl+'create-with-file', formData));
}
```

3. In Web API, modify the `CreateWithFile` action to receive the `createdUpload` object with the `FromForm` attribute.

```cs
public IActionResult CreateWithFile([FromForm] CreatedUpload createdUpload)
```

Comment: my good sir, you are my life saver, thank you very much :D